# Insert number of records based off results from a count query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an application that tracks actions taken by admins in and `admin_comments` table.

Recently, I have been asked to create a new table `admin_stats` that keeps track of the productivity of certain areas of the application.

I've implemented this in to my code logic and so going forward all stats are tracked, but they have asked me if I can also add in all the previous stats by searching through the `admin_comments` table for appropriate fields.

My `admin_comments` table looks like this:

```
+----+---------+----------+---------+------+
| id | user_id | admin_id | comment | type |
+----+---------+----------+---------+------+
```

And the `admin_stats` table like this:

```
+----+----------+---------+------+--------+
| id | admin_id | user_id | type | action |
+----+----------+---------+------+--------+
```

To start with I just want to import claims in to this table. A claim is either `approved`, `rejected`, `temporarily rejected`, or `permanently rejected` and I have got the count of each action from the admins using this query:

```
select admin_id, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN comment like 'Approved the claim for%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Approved,
    SUM(CASE WHEN comment like 'Rejected the claim for%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Rejected,
    SUM(CASE WHEN comment like 'Temporarily rejected (24 hour hold) the claim for%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TempReject, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN comment like 'Permanently rejected the claim for%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as PermReject
from admin_comments
where admin_id > 0
group by admin_id
```

Which produces results like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can then perform an insert based off the count for each `admin_id`?

i.e From the image above I would want to insert one record in to `admin_stats` for an approved `action` with the `type` as application and one record for a rejected `action` with the `type` as application for the `admin_id` 1.

For `admin_id` 4 I would want to insert 25 approved `actions`, 12 rejected `actions`, and 2 `tempreject` actions.

So each action should be entered as a new row, the `type` will always be application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this.

```
insert into admin_stats(admin_id,type,action) --add other columns as needed
select admin_id,'application' as type,
case when comment like 'Approved the claim for%' then 'Approved'
     when comment like 'Rejected the claim for%' then 'Rejected'
     when comment like 'Temporarily rejected (24 hour hold) the claim for%' then 'TempReject'
     when comment like 'Permanently rejected the claim for%' then 'PermReject'
end as action
from admin_comments
where admin_id > 0
and (comment like 'Approved the claim for%'
     or comment like 'Rejected the claim for%'
     or comment like 'Temporarily rejected (24 hour hold) the claim for%'
     or comment like 'Permanently rejected the claim for%')
```